# Call count result from stored procedure MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a value from a stored procedure in php but I can't do it.

My stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_table;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_table()
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

My PHP code:

```
$recordSet_table = $conn->query("CALL sp_table()");

print_r($recordSet_table)."<br><br>";
```

Comment: How about using an `out` parameter?

Comment: Can you give an example how to do it, please?

Comment: Thank you, I have found solution for this issue

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code.

$sql = mysqli_query($connectionVariable,"CALL `sp_table`(@count)");

$result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);